# screen coordinates inside a grid libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I've created a grid using ShapeRenderer.line. It draws a 10x10 grid.

```
private void setupCamera() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        camera = new OrthographicCamera(VIEWPORT_WIDTH, VIEWPORT_HEIGHT);
        camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth / 2, camera.viewportHeight / 2, 0f);
        camera.update();
    }

@Override
public void draw() {
     for(int x = 0; x < rows; x++){
         for(int y = 0; y < columns; y++){

                 shapeRenderer.line(x+1, 12-y, x+2, 12-y);
                 shapeRenderer.line(x+1, 12-y, x+1, 11-y);
                 shapeRenderer.line(x+2, 12-y, x+2, 11-y);
                 shapeRenderer.line(x+1, 11-y, x+2, 11-y);
         }
     }
  }

public class Cell 
{
   private static int gridWidth = 1;
   private static int gridHeight = 1;

   public int coordinatesX;
   public int coordinatesY;

   public Cell(){}

   public Cell(int x, int y){

     this.coordinatesX = x;
     this.coordinatesY = y;
   }

   public void drawLine(ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer){

     int left = coordinatesX * gridWidth;
     int right = left + gridWidth;
     int bottom = coordinatesY * gridHeight;
     int top= bottom + gridHeight;

     shapeRenderer.line(left , top, left, bottom);
     shapeRenderer.line(right , top, right , bottom);
     shapeRenderer.line(left , top, right , top);
     shapeRenderer.line(left , bottom, right , bottom);
   }

   public void drawImageStartPosition(SpriteBatch spritebatch, int x, int y, Texture texture){

    int left = x * texture.getWidth();
    int bottom = y * texture.getHeight(); 

    spritebatch.draw(texture, left, bottom, texture.getWidth(), texture.getHeight());
}
```

}

I've created a texture (ball.png) and what I'm trying to accomplish is I want to place that texture inside a cell (using screen coordinates of that particular cell) based on the grid I've created.

Anybody can give me a pointer into how I should go about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try turning each grid cell into an object.

```
public class GridSquare {

    private static int gridWidth = 10;
    private static int gridHeight = 10;

    public final int xPos;
    public final int yPos;

    public GridSquare(int x, int y){
        xPos = x;
        yPos = y;
    }

    public void drawOutLine(ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer){

         /*
         If the gridWidth and gridHeight don't change over time then you can
         move the calculation of the left, right, bottom and top positions 
         into the constructor for better performance.
         */
         int left = xPos * gridWidth;
         int right = left + gridWidth;
         int bottom = yPos * gridHeight;
         int top= bottom + gridHeight;

         shapeRenderer.line(left , top, left, bottom);
         shapeRenderer.line(right , top, right , bottom);
         shapeRenderer.line(left , top, right , top);
         shapeRenderer.line(left , bottom, right , bottom);
    }

    public void drawImage(Spritebatch spritebatch, Texture texture){

         /*
         If the gridWidth and gridHeight don't change over time then you can
         move the calculation of the left and bottom positions 
         into the constructor for better performance.
         */

        int left = xPos * gridWidth;
        int bottom = yPos * gridHeight; 

        spritebatch.draw(
                texture,
                left,
                bottom,
                gridWidth,
                gridHeight
        );
    }
}
```

Then you can iterate over them and tell them to render themselves and they will know how to do it.

```
 shapeRenderer.begin();
 for(int x = 0; x < rows; x++){
     for(int y = 0; y < columns; y++){
         gridSquares[x][y].drawOutLine(shapeRenderer);
     }
 }
 shapeRenderer.end();


 spritebatch.begin();
 for(int x = 0; x < rows; x++){
     for(int y = 0; y < columns; y++){
         // Assuming you have loaded the png image into a variable named balltexture
         gridSquares[x][y].drawImage(spritebatch, balltexture);
     }
 }
 spritebatch.end();
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll work up on that answer. Another thing, before drawing my 10x10 grid, I've called the shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined). From what I've read,  this changes the coordinate system. Is there a way to match for example the shapeRenderer.line coordinates with that of the spritebatch.draw coordinates?

Comment: SpriteBatch has a similar method setProjectionMatrix. Setting the projection matrices for the ShapeRenderer and SpriteBatch to a cameras combined matrix will ensure that the shapes and images are drawn in the same coordinate space.

http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.html#setProjectionMatrix-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Matrix4-

Comment: I've set the Spritebatch setProjectionMatrix with camera.combined (spritebatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined)) and the grid looks ok; yet it made the balltexture.png image huge. And it's a small picture 32x28 pixels. How do I get it back its normal size?

Comment: What kind of camera are you using? It should probably be orthographic.

Also what did you set grid width and height to?

Posting your updated code would be helpful.

Comment: I've updated my code for the camera. I used VIEWPORT_WIDTH = 20 and VIEWPORT_HEIGHT = 13. I didn't set the grid width and height as I'm  just using the line coordinates to draw the grid

Comment: I believe that the VIEWPORT_WIDTH and VIEWPORT_HEIGHT are pixel lengths, so 20 and 13 are extremely low, try changing them to something like 800 * 600 to begin with.